# Programmatically set the position of CKEditor's dialogs

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically set the position of a CKEditor dialog whenever a new one is opened up.  The actual setting of the position part seems easy, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to trap the event of a new CKEditor dialog being created and shown.

I'm assuming it will be something along the lines of...

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogCreated', function(e) { ... } );
```

But can't seem to actually find it in the documentation.

Comment: Be sure to reattach the default events as oleq mentions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752180/ckeditor-3-dialog-positioning/12764449#12764449

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending several hours today, I was able to figure this out by complete luck.  Dialog definitions can be manipulated at load time.  Within your `config.js` file, add the following:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(e) {
    var dialogName = e.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;

    dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
        // Calculate your newX and newY ...
        this.move(newX, newY);
    }
}
```

If you want to adjust the position for a specific dialog you can use `dialogName` to test for it.