# How to get X Y position of scroll/mouse/cursor of CKEDITOR Text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom, ckeditor

I am using `CKEDITOR 4`. How to find out the ***scroll/mouse/cursor X Y position***  (*not of the window*)?

I've tested the below code but its giving the window's scroll position:

```
var win = new CKEDITOR.dom.window( window );
var pos = win.getScrollPosition();
alert( "pos.x :: " + pos.x + " pos.y :: " + pos.y );
```

I need the X Y position of the CKEDITOR text area instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var selectedRange = selected.getRanges()[0];
var node = selectedRange.startContainer;
var value = node.getText();
var position = selectedRange.endOffset;
```

or check out [this reference](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/)

here's the code just in case the link breaks!

```
 function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
     if (document.selection) {
         ctrl.focus ();
         var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
         Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
         CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
      }
   // Firefox support
   else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
          return (CaretPos);
       }
  function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
      if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
      ctrl.focus();
      ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
    var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', pos);
    range.moveStart('character', pos);
    range.select();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks Rachel... but this gives the position of the cursor **in that particular node**. but i want to know wrt the whole content...

Comment: aha now i understand. will try to post alternative solution

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984338/ckeditor-dialog-positioning